# Bind9 and Debian10, can't run named

Tags: linux, debian, bind

I'm using Debian 10. I installed bind9:

```
sudo apt-get install bind9 bind9utils dnsutils
```

I prepared my own conf file (in path `/home/student/dns/myconf.conf`):

```
options {
directory "/var/named";
listen-on port 53 {127.0.0.1;};
transfer-source 127.0.0.1;
};
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
controls{
inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow {127.0.0.1;}
keys{rndc-key;};
};
```

Checked it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 stop
sudo rndc-confgen -a -u bind -t /home/student/dns
sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 start
```

Tried to run it then:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/named -u bind -t /home/student/dns
```

But when I did it, I wanted to check ifit works:

```
sudo ps aux | grep named
```

But it showed NOTHING. When I do `sudo service bind9 status` it is activated. What's wrong? Should I use chroot or something? Why this does not work?

Moreover, I can't make Bind to take logs ..

Comment: Did you tell named to use `myconf.conf` instead of its usual `named.conf`? Did you check the messages written in syslog (where named usually tells why it doesn't work)?

Comment: @user1686: How can I say to name to use `myconf.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

The default location for BIND config file is at

`/etc/bind/named.conf`

You can confirm which .conf file is loaded by looking in the system logs

```
cat /var/log/syslog |grep "loading configuration"
```

You might see one of these errors

```
May 13 02:16:17 debian named[1947]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf' 
May 13 02:21:07 debian named[2078]: loading configuration: permission denied 
May 13 02:23:38 debian named[2149]: loading configuration: file not found
```

You also need to use the -c option to specify your own configuration file.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/named -c /home/madato/dns/myconf.conf
```

However, I have not been able to successfully start **named** on Debian 10 when the CONF file is under any other directory than the default **/etc/bind/**

There appears to be some hard coded check that only allows **named** to read a **conf file** that is in that specific directory.

I suggest keeping your myconf.conf file in /etc/bind/ and trying again. Or use a soft-link file pointing to the original.